# ENOENT: no such file or directory Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, github

I'm trying to display the content of a html file into node js file using readFileSync(). But I get this error :

```
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'index.html'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:284:15)
    at port (/app/web.js:6:22)
    at callbacks (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:161:37)
    at param (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:135:11)
    at pass (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:142:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:170:5)
    at Object.router (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
    at next (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
    at Object.expressInit [as handle] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/middleware.js:30:5)
```

Here is my web.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer(express.logger());
var fs=require('fs');
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
//  response.send('Hello World2 !');
response.send(fs.readFileSync('index.html').toString());
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, function() {
 console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

The "web.js" file and the "index.html" are in my github repository in the following address:

```
https://github.com/myUsername/bitstarter/blob/master/node-js-sample/web.js 
https://github.com/myUsername/bitstarter/blob/master/node-js-sample/index.html
```

I tried different paths to address "index.html" none worked, such as

```
 /bitstarter/blob/master/node-js-sample/index.html
/node-js-sample/index.html
/bitstarter/node-js-sample/index.html
./index.html
```

!
I'm using AWS EC2 ubuntun 12-4.
I've been straggling with this error for hours! Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The line that says `app.get('/', ...` means "when the client asks for '/'..." That is: it maps "web space" (URL paths) into actions. In your case -- read and return the contents of `index.html`.

So the proper request in your case is just `www.mydomain.com/`.

If you want to be able to serve static files, read up on `express.static()`

Answer (score 1):

As Nitzan mentioned, in the long run you will want to learn how to use express.static() to serve html files and templates as you build out your node app. In response to your present question, however, I recommend the following:

1. Save the `index.html` file into the same directory as your web.js file in you EC2 instance (i.e. don't try to remotely access it on your github page).
2. Use the following code:

> var content = fs.readFileSync('index.html', 'utf-8');
>   response.send(content);

This will read the contents of your `index.html` file into a variable called `content` while specifying the proper encoding. Then it will instruct node to send the content to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that you are not adding "index.html" in git. Fist you need to add this to git and then push to heroku. This will solve your problem. Hope it helps :)